# Multiple histogram based on groupby and for different column

Tags: python, pandas

I am just new in pandas. I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Group = ['A','B','A','B','B','A','A','B','A','B']

Weight = np.random.uniform(0.1, 2, size=10)

Parameter_1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=10)

Parameter_2 = np.random.randint(low =1, high = 5, size=10)

Parameter_3 = np.random.randint(low =1, high = 5, size=10)


data = pd.DataFrame({'Group':Group, 
   'Weight':Weight,'Parameter_1':Parameter_1,'Parameter_2':Parameter_2, 
   'Parameter_3':Parameter_3})
```

I am trying to create a separate PDF for each group containing the histograms based on `Parameter_1`, `Parameter_2`, `Parameter_3` and their `Weight`.

Not quite sure as attack the problem :(

Thanks
Mick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you wanted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in data['Group'].unique():
    data.loc[data['Group']==i].hist()
    plt.savefig('path/to/file{}.pdf'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will save a file as `Group_name.pdf` in your working directory. You may change the path as you wish.

```
# Columns to get histograms
names = list(data.columns)
names.remove('Group')
print(names)

['Parameter_1', 'Parameter_2', 'Parameter_3', 'Weight']

# plotting
for i in (data['Group'].unique()):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(names),1)
    group_data = data.loc[data['Group']==i]
    for number, col_name in enumerate(names):
        ax[number].hist(data[col_name]);
        ax[number].set_title("Histogram for " + col_name)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(i+'.pdf') # provide a valid path
```

Comment: Hi, sorry If i didnt explain properly. What I am try to do is to create 2 PDFs file (one for group A and one for B). In each PDF I want 3 figures showing distribution of parameter 1,2 and 3. As you can see all three parameters are integer which can vary between 1 and 5. I intended those as categories. The histograms should be expressed as relative frequencies weighed based on the weigh column.

Comment: I was thinking about a for loop which says for each group in data, create an histogram1, histogram2 and histogram3 and save all three as a PDF. I tried data.groupby[‘Group’] but it get messy.

Comment: @Tani84 I've realized my answer is not correct. I didn't get the part `The histograms should be expressed as relative frequencies weighed based on the weigh column`. Can you elaborate? Also, `Parameter_1` is not integer as you've mentioned.

Comment: Hi akilat90, thanks for your help. I think it is probably easier if I share with you the actual csv file with the data with an example of what I am tryng to achieve. Is there any way I can do that?